# how to add menu in a button

Tags: extjs

I want to have menu in a button as drop-down without the key "text" in ext js 4. I have an array with me with the required field to be shown in button. And I am associating this array in the menu option programatically. But this array does not have "text" as its column.  Please help.  Regards,
Ranjeet Kanth

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
          x: 5,
     y: 5,
     text: 'Add Language',
     showText: true,
     width: 120,
          menu : menu1 });

var menu1 = {
            items: [{entryName:'English'},{entryName:'English(US)'}]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong component... you should be using a split button:

`Ext.create('Ext.button.split', { ... });`